# how to access controls inside Ajax accordion in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have Ajax accordion inside Update panel, the update panel inside master page content.
my Accordion has In each Pane (labels , Buttons, Hidden Field ) when i can't access labels 
i try the following :
-to get all controls in Document

```
var count=document.forms[0].length;
var i=0;
var eleName; 
for (i=0; i < count; i++ )
{
    eleName=document.forms[0].elements[i].id; 
    alert(eleName);  
    if(eleName.indexOf("Label_Charge_1") != -1)
    {
        alert('the required control');  
    }
}
```

but it return only buttons and hidden fields

I tried:

```
document.getElementById('<%=Label_Charge_1.ClientID %>')
```

but it's return null also I tried $get $find but nothing return the labels inside panes in the accordion 
I want to access the label in JavaScript to make it visible or in visible with the user click on pane header

Comment: are you trying to get the element at the right time? is it already inserted? go into sourcecode, compare if your id in html and the id you have in your finder-function are the same. if yes, try to search directly in you browser console.